# How is RAID3/4 is implemented for more than 4 drives?

Tags: raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, raid5

I understand that, RAID 3/4 for 4 drives is: Parity Drive = D1 XOR D2 XOR D3. But what is there 5 drives or more? For example 5 or 6. How many parity drives is needed, and how XOR algorithm is working for this case?

Comment: What is the use case for RAID 4 (dedicated parity drive) vs RAID 5, which distributes the parity and resolves any issues with the number of disks in the array?

Comment: I see this as more of an educational question. (Which of course makes it off topic for ServerFault.)

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt what is a site of stackexchange for such questions?

Comment: Super User seems a good choice to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any number of bits can be XOR'd, and you can always regenerate the data of a failed drive by XORing all the other drives.

This means that this algorithm can only replace a single failed disk, regardless of how many disks are in the array, and it needs to know which disk has failed.

For RAID6, a second checksum disk is used that uses a different algorithm, so the data can still be reconstructed if (any) two disks fail.